# After upgrading a VM to 12.04 my eth0 MAC is all zeroes

Tags: networking, xen

I did a series of upgrades from 10.04 to 12.04 on a VM under Xen virtualisation. Now for some reason eth0 won't start up, ifconfig says mac address is 00:00:00:00:00:00, I've tried setting the address but the network still refuses to come up.

I've rebooted into DSL and managed to run ifconfig, and this is the result
[image: ifconfig]

Something in the new release broke networking. How can I find out what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with this VMs OpenVZ container. Unfortunately I have no information on how it got fixed.